# Given a normed vector space $X$, can you always define a bounded linear functional $f$ which is bounded above and below by the norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a (possibly infinite-dimensional) normed vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, whose norm is denoted $|| \cdot ||$.

Given two non-negative scalars, say $M, N \in \mathbb{R}$ with $M < N$, can you always find a bounded linear functional $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $M||x|| \leq | f(x) | \leq N || x||$ for all $x \in X$?

Obviously, if $f$ is bounded then $|f(x)| \leq ||f||_{op} || x|| \leq K || x||$ for some non-negative $K \in \mathbb{R}$. But this fact is kind of going in the "wrong direction" so I'm not too sure if this is helpful.

It does seem like there are several corollaries to the Hahn-Banach theorem that might also be related, but again, I'm not sure if there are additional assumptions that I would need to make to force this question to have a positive answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is never the case if the dimension is bigger than $1$ and $M>0$, simply because you will have a nontrivial kernel. On the other hand if $M\leq 0$, then that part of the condition is automatically satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

If $M=0$ then the answer is clearly YES. If $M >0$ then the condition $M\|x\|\leq |f(x)|$ implies thast $f$ is one-to-one. This forces your space $X$ to be one-dimensional.

Comment: Thanks - what about the other part of the inequality? Given any arbitrary real number $N > 0$ can I be sure that I can construct a linear functional $f$ s.t. $|f(x)| \leq N || x ||$?

Comment: Certainly. Take any non-zero continuous linear functional and divide it by by  a large integer to make its norm less than or equal to $N$. @gogoTOP